# Line selection not working properly on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

My line selection is acting very weird on VSCode. It goes in this weird multi-line edit mode. I am unable to select multiple lines fully by dragging my mouse down on lines. Even when I use shift and down arrow it does not select the whole line.

Mouse drag selection not working:

[image]

Keyboard Shift + Down Arrow not working:

[image]

Comment: can you lock the question or mark it as solved? there 5 answers with the same idea...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On Mac the solution was simple go to the menu "Selection" and deselect the option "Column Selection Mode".

Now it works as expected.

[image: code selection]

Answer (score 6):

Two things I use:

- I select full lines by clicking and dragging in the 'numbers' columns
- For multi-line to work I use the menu option -> Selection -> Column Select Mode

Comment: I want to disable multi line select. This is not how the cursor behaves normally in any of my IDEs. Even in VSCode it didn't behave like this before.

Comment: Yes I get it.  it has changed.  Didn't used to be like this.  other IDE's aren't. ok. ok.  that's annoying.  Now to the issue - do you want to be able to select lines - how about using the line number column - is that helping?  VScode changes a loot (I notice this change too).  You'll need to focus on how to achieve your goal, possible including a change in what you do to copy and paste.

Comment: Yeah, the line number way is working. But this change to the default method is just stupid.

Comment: Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Hi i had the same problem and fixed it by deselecting the "Column Selection Mode" inside the Selection menu. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Resolved it as below.

1. Go to Selection menu in vs code menu bar.
2. Untick on Column Selection Mode option.

Answer (score 1):

go to file, preference, settings and search for Editor:Column Selection and desable. this solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. If you wish to perform the desired selection without changing the settings, then hit the ALT key and drag your mouse
2. Or, just Go to Selection menu in VS code menu and untick the Column Selection Mode option.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to Selection menu in vs code menu bar.

**Untick on Column Selection Mode option.**